# Is SVG different in every program?

Tags: svg, rendering

*(I don't think this is the correct SE, but I couldn't find a better one.)*

Someone I know asked for help in a problem they're having, but since I'm not directly an expert in the required field (only adjacent) I'm relying this question here:

Are there any ambiguities in how SVG is rendered?  They say that their image is rendered very different in every program they tried (this would be Microsoft Word, Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Inkscape, and some not further specified Delphi library).  To my understanding after searching the web together with my prior knowledge on the subject are SVG images completely defined except for three things:

- The font of the text (the font is dependent on what's the closest available to the specified one is).
- The precise rendering of incorrect, non-standard-compliant SVG (or non-SVG it is then of course :) ) is AFAIK not defined.
- Usage of extra-specificational things like CSS, JavaScript or Inkscape's extensions are not necessarily supported by a given renderer (this includes advanced versions of the SVG standard – SVGB and SVGF – and – as we will see later – different versions).
- (added by edit; see below) Some renderers are case sensitive while some are case insensitive (although I think the standard does specify what the correct thing is).

They said that the only problem that they were (after many pains) able to fix was the scaling of the image (what implies that the other issues are even bigger, but I don't know the specifics).

I tried to trigger differences in the programs that I have available on this my Linux machine.  I created an image in Inkscape and then tried out all programs I could think of.  Some displayed it like Inkscape, but most were missing the objects with mesh gradients.  Like Inkscape were Inkscape (duh) and ImageMagick (by converting it to PNG), while Firefox, GIMP, Eye Of Gnome, ghostwriter, LibreOffice Draw, Kdenlive, Gnumeric and GNOME Drawing weren't.  [Apparently](https://librearts.org/2018/05/gradient-meshes-and-hatching-to-be-removed-from-svg-2-0/) mesh gradients are about to be thrown out of the standard, so this weird behavior is actually correct, but I don't think that this is their problem, because a) why give every (or at least many) objects a mesh gradient in their pretty easy use case (creating a couple nice graphs) and b) as I said the one problem they said that they have is an issue with scaling which is 1) not that one and 2) not something I could reproduce.

Any help is highly appreciated.  Thanks!

–––– EDIT ––––

I finally got a bit more information.  The first problem was the now above mentioned inconsistency in case sensitivity.  The second problem is that apparently Word can't really convert SVG to it's internal format and so is not usable as an *v*ector *g*raphics file format.  Another problem is that only some of the units for specifying font size seem to be interpreted consistently.

The weirdest problem is that the vertical placement of the text is – and I quote – "more random than anything" even though it [seems](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text#attributes) that this cannot be and they now fix it manually every time.

Comment: The only way to achieve a more consistent rendering is to **inspect the actual svg code**. There are too many reasons for inconsistent rendering in applications. In general try to comply with older specs e.g svg 1 and replace newer features with older ones (e.g pathLength with calculated stroke dash values). Many graphics applications have either limited or no CSS support - prefer attributes. Support for Filters or referenced elements like `<use>` (might need the deprecated `xlink:href`)? The list goes on and on.  Rendering problems can only be solved individually for each file.

Comment: If they had "issues with scaling", it is most probable the problem was not the renderer. Scaling behavior is unambiguously described in SVG and support is mostly stable (with one exeption: the `transform` attribute on `<svg>` elements), but it is difficult to understand – easily the most asked about aspect here on SO. Also, often editors do not give the best support in developing that part. And then there is the interaction of SVG-defined scaling with external mechanisms, like when embedding SVG in HTML/CSS. How box sizing and image scaling affect each other is not always obvious.

Comment: Re Inkscape: it has two modes of saving files that will help a lot with compatibility: The **Save as...** command has modes **Standard SVG** and **Optimized SVG**. Both will convert Inkscape-internal features to standard-compliant ones.

Comment: The only software that can be relied on to have rendering closely accurate to the spec are browsers, and programs like Inkscape (since it uses SVG as its file format).  If SVG support is secondary to the main function of the app, then the authors are unlikely to have spent the time to get all SVG features implemented fully and accurately.  Even software like Adobe Illustrator still has big gaps in it's SVG import and export.  Despite having a large development team, and supporting SVG for a long time.

Comment: (..cont.)  Having said that, as long as the SVG is not using the more advanced features of the SVG specification, like filters, or more recent SVG2 features, then most things should render the SVG acceptably.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Apart from Word all of the software they used are browsers or Inkscape, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Ok. As @herrstrietzel said, we really need more information (such as sample file(s)) to give better advice.  Right now, we  can only speculate.